# ¿Porque no puedo ver los Datos en el QtableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, sqlite3

estoy con un proyecto escolar... en donde usamos una base de datos simple de sqlite3... mi problema es que no puedo lograr cargar los datos al tablewidget de mi ventana... este es el codigo principal:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from funciones import mostrartabla

class VentanaPrincipal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VentanaPrincipal,self).__init__()
        loadUi("ventana.ui",self)
        self.cargartabla()
    
    def cargartabla(self):
        self.table = QTableWidget()
        datos = mostrartabla()
        self.table.setRowCount(50)
        fila = 0
        for registro in datos:
            self.table.setItem(fila, 0, QTableWidgetItem(registro[0]))
            self.table.setItem(fila,1, QTableWidgetItem(registro[1]))      
            self.table.setItem(fila,2, QTableWidgetItem(registro[2]))
            self.table.setItem(fila,3, QTableWidgetItem(registro[3]))                
            self.table.setItem(fila,4, QTableWidgetItem(registro[4])) 
            self.table.setItem(fila,5, QTableWidgetItem(registro[5]))
            self.table.setItem(fila,6, QTableWidgetItem(str(registro[6])))
            fila+=1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mi_app = VentanaPrincipal()
    mi_app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

y el la funcion que realiza la consulta:

```
def mostrartabla():
    conector = sqlite3.connect("base1.db")
    cursor = conector.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM articulos")
    datos = cursor.fetchall()
    return datos
```

el editor no me notifica de ningun error. pero al ejecutar el codigo siempre veo la tabla vacia

Comment: Se te olvidó establecer el número de columnas de la tabla. Probablemente es por eso que no da el resultado esperado.

Comment: acabo de agregarlo pero el resultado no cambia... sigue mostrando una tabla en blanco... :/

Comment: Entonces, no se que pueda ser. Revisaste que la base de datos tenga contenido?

Comment: ya revise la base y las consultas sqlite... la verdad todo eso esta bien... el unico problema es que no puedo mostrar los datos en la interface...

Comment: Los datos son los que no se ven o la tabla entera?

Comment: los datos no se cargan en la tabla... por ejemplo si agrego un print(registro) dentro del for.... puedo ver los datos en la terminal de salida... pero no aparecen en el TableWidget...

Answer (score 0):

en lo personal uso el método propio que trae pyqt para leer archivos bd.
Como quiero usar un ejemplo casi funcional,dado que cada cual usa la base que quiera y usar un entorno en si mismo hago un código nuevo en los aspectos visuales.

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
import sys


class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conectar = Conectar()
        self.apariencia()
    
    def apariencia(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Mostrar base - bd')
        self.resize(677,700)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Sanserif", 12))
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget(self)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 675, 699))
        self.table = QTableWidget(0, 6,self)
        self.table.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 670, 570))
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Número 1', 'Número 2', 'Número 3','Número 4','Número 5','Número 6']) 
        self.consulta()         
        self.show()
            
    def consulta(self):
        orden = 'Select * from articulos'
        index = 0
        query = QSqlQuery()
        query.exec_(orden)
        while query.next():
            self.table.setRowCount(index + 1)
            self.table.setItem(index, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(0))))
            self.table.setItem( index,1, QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(1))))            
            self.table.setItem( index,2, QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(2)))) 
            self.table.setItem(index, 3, QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(3)))) 
            self.table.setItem(index, 4, QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(4)))) 
            self.table.setItem(index, 5, QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(5))))  
            index += 1    
    
 
class Conectar():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        self.db.setDatabaseName('base1.db')
        
        if not self.db.open():
            QMessageBox.critical(None,'Error','No se pudo abrir la base',QMessageBox.Cancel)    

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mi_app= Principal()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

¿qué es lo diferente más allá de lo visual?

con la clase conectar hago el enlace con el archivo que contiene los datos

y con el método consulta, solo para que sea más fácil de leer, en orden pongo el tipo de filtrado que estás usando y lo necesario para mostrarla, lo único que hay que llamarla, lo cual hago en el método apariencia.
Espero te sirva.

Comment: ya pude solucionarlo...por alguna razon el problema era """ self.table = QTableWidget()""" paso lo mismo luego con un boton, solo borrando esa linea ambas cosas funcionaron bien... desconozco por que sera :/ ....